# getJSON getting all items but has undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using `getJSON` for my JSON data items, like this:

```
$.getJSON(projects, function (json) {
        var firstThree = json.sort(function(a, b) { return a.Variable1 < b.Variable1 ? 1 : -1; })
        .slice(0, 3);
        var related = firstThree;
        var i = '';
        $.each(json, function(i) {
            var sizeClass = JSON.stringify(related[i].pname);
            console.log('sifzdfze'+sizeClass);
        });
```

I checked on console, getting sizeClass item, it works. But but it also shows an error:

```
 related[i] is undefined
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the line: var i = ''; It is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you are accessing `related` as an array. So you are supposed to iterate over the items in the array. In your case `related[i]` is `undefined` because you are trying to access an item that is out of bounds of the particular array.

```
$.each(json, function(i) {
```

supposed to be

```
$.each(related, function(val, i) {
```

Also the above line, creates an `i` that is scoped to the `each` callback. So there is not need to declare it in the line above.
Here `val` is the current value in iteration whose index is `i`. It can be simplified as

```
$.each(related, function(val, i) {
   var sizeClass = JSON.stringify(val.pname);
```

Comment: Also, the second element of the callback is the current element of the loop, so he can use this instead of indexing the array.